# Pegar os bytes do arquivo e gerar um hash

Tags: java, hash

Galera estou lendo uma arquivo txt da seguinte maneira, como eu faria para guardar os bytes do arquivo e gerar um hash sha-256 a classe que gera eu também ja possuo o código, como eu faço para guarda em uma array de bytes ou outras sugestões . Peço desculpa sou iniciante em java

```
try {
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("c://teste.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String linha = reader.readLine();
            while (linha != null) {
                System.out.println(linha);
                linha = reader.readLine();
                }
                reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Erro ao tentar ler o arquivo " + e);
                }
```

codigo que uso para gerar hash

```
 MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
 byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest(linha.getBytes("UTF-8"));

                             System.out.println(messageDigest);
                             StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
                             for (byte b : messageDigest) {
                               hexString.append(String.format("%02X", 0xFF & b));
                             }
                             String senhahex = hexString.toString();

                             System.out.println(senhahex);
```